# How to send bbox dynamically via wms request in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms

I've created a leaflet map and use **L.tileLayer.wms** to load my wms layer. I dont want to load all data on my map instead  i need to load data based on bbox.I use this line for sending wms request to geoserver :

```
L.tileLayer
  .wms(elm.GIS_LayersAddressMapServer.trim(), {
    layers: elm.GIS_LayersName,
    format: "image/png",
    transparent: true,
    tiled: true,
    maxZoom: 25,
    bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

but in network console i have this :

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms
  ?service=WMS
  &request=GetMap
  &layers=cite%3APTL_Tower
  &styles=
  &format=image%2Fpng
  &transparent=true
  &version=1.1.1
  &tiled=true
  &bbox=25.0927734375%2C22.836945920943855%2C78.22265625000001%2C41.50857729743935
  &width=256
  &height=256
  &srs=EPSG%3A3857
  &bbox=5165920.119625352,4226661.916057106,5322463.153553394,4383204.949985149
```

as you see bbox is sent twice and doesn't show me anything. How can i handle this problem ?

Comment: `L.tileLayer.wms` creates it's own `bbox` parameter when creating `wms` request, so specifying additional one won't help. Instead try with Leaflet's `bounds` option.

Comment: TomazicM - what do you mean by bounds ?. you mean i ought to create wms request and pass bounds to it ? could you please send me a sample .

Comment: `L.tileLayer.wms` layer inherits `bounds` option of general `L.GridLayer` layer, see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer

Comment: TomazicM - tnx alot. but i still can't find any proper method to handle my problem !

Comment: Edit your question and describe what have you tried and still does not work as expected.

Comment: TomazicM - I want to set bound option in wms url like this :
L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/GIS/wms', { layers: 'GIS:River', format: 'image/png', transparent: true, tiled: true , bound : myBoxingBound }). but after adding leaflet creates its own bbox option

Comment: It was clearly stated: Please, edit your question … It's time consuming to go through all comments and find relevant info.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you already defined bound to your map object (like this https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlngbounds). Try something like this:

```js
L.tileLayer
  .wms(elm.GIS_LayersAddressMapServer.trim(), {
    layers: elm.GIS_LayersName,
    format: "image/png",
    transparent: true,
    tiled: true,
    maxZoom: 25,
    bounds: map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

For more details use: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-wms-bounds